# How an I change the color of a specific table cell when hovering on its row?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I'm trying to make my table data change color upon hovering over a table row. Is that possible? I tried searching everywhere, but none seems to match my description.

I want to only change the color of "Hello World" when I am hovering over the table row. So when i hover over **anywhere in the table row**, only that table data "Hello World" will change color.

```css
table tr:hover {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Hello World </td>
      <td> Greetings </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by change table data color? Do you want to change color of that row when hovering over it? Or, you want to change color of any specific cell of that row?

Comment: i want to change that specific cell of that row. Example, the table data which have 'Hello World' should change color when i hover over that particular table row

Comment: not exactly what i meant. what if there are more than one cell in a row? do you want to change any specific cell color or the whole row color?

Comment: I think there is no difference when hovering because the color is on black anyway

Comment: And the color is already black, so you wouldn't even notice the hover at this point

Comment: yes, i want to change only one specific cell color

Comment: @j08691 sorry, that was only an example, i have changed it.

Comment: What are the parameters of "hello world"? Is it the first cell? Is it the cell with that exact text content? It's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want a specific cell to change upon hovering over any part of the table row, give that cell a class and use that in your selector:

```css
table tr:hover td.change{
  color: white
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="change"> Hello World </td>
      <td> Greetings </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will set the color for the first cell when the row is hovered.

```css
tr {
  color: blue;
}

tr:hover td:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td> Hello World </td>
  <td> Greetings </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This will set the color for any cell with the `accent` class when the row is hovered.

```css
tr {
  color: blue;
}

tr:hover .accent {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="accent"> Hello World </td>
  <td> Greetings </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have also tried this, but the specific table data "hello world" will not change color when i hover over the table data "greetings"

Comment: updated answer and fiddle to change the whole row, not just the cell

Comment: You're changing the color for _all_ cells. I don't think that was the request.

Comment: Ah, it looks like @j08691 has the correct answer, but updated answer in case he wanted to just do the first child as well